# Error when building a MapReduce program in Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I get the below error when building a MapReduce file in Hadoop.
I am using Cloudera hadoop distribution.
testmr_classes is a folder and TestMR.java is the MapReduce file

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ echo `hadoop classpath`
/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/.//*
[cloudera@localhost ~]$

[cloudera@localhost ~]$ javac -classpath `hadoop classpath`:. -d testmr_classes TestMR.java
TestMR.java:32: TestMR.Reduce is not abstract and does not override abstract method reduce(org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable,java.util.Iterator<org.apache.hadoop.io.Text>,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector<org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable,org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable>,org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter) in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer
    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,DoubleWritable>
                  ^
1 error
[cloudera@localhost ~]$
```

The below are the contents of TestMR.java,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class TestMR 
{
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,Text>
    {
        private IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
        private Text value = new Text();

        public void map(IntWritable key, Text line, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            String [] split = line.toString().split(",");
            key.set(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));

            if(split[2] == "Test")
            {
                value.set(split[4] + "," + split[7]);
                output.collect(key, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable,Text,IntWritable,DoubleWritable>
    {
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> v, OutputCollector<IntWritable, DoubleWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            Iterator values = v.iterator();
            while(values.hasNext())
            {
                String [] tmp_buf_1 = values.next().toString().split(",");
                String V1 = tmp_buf_1[0];
                String T1 = tmp_buf_1[1];

                if(!values.hasNext())   
                    break;  

                String [] tmp_buf_2 = values.next().toString().split(",");       
                String V2 = tmp_buf_2[0];
                String T2 = tmp_buf_2[1];           

                double dResult = (Double.parseDouble(V2) - Double.parseDouble(V1)) / (Double.parseDouble(T2) - Double.parseDouble(T1));

                output.collect(key, new DoubleWritable(dResult));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(TestMR.class);
        conf.setJobName("TestMapReduce");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

This is my first attempt at MapReduce and would be glad to know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Also, never compare Strings with ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the second arg of your reduce() and the error. You wrote Iterable but it gives you an Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your class path in place of 'hadoop classpath', such as:

```
javac -classpath /opt/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-core-1.1.2.jar:/opt/hadoop-1.1.2/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d testmr_classes TestMR.java
```

The exact path depends on where you installed hadoop.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my question. 

Can you please look at the command trace again and comment?

Also, Do you happen to know all the default jars to be included in the classpath ?

Comment: can you try by changing map and reduce class names to something like MapClass and ReduceClass....